# Creating DXF Spline programmatically

Tags: spline, autodesk, dxf

I need to create spline programmatically. I've made something like:

```
0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1006
  0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
TABLES
  0
TABLE
2
LAYER
  0
LAYER
 2
shape
 70
 64
 62
 250
 6
CONTINUOUS
 0
LAYER
 2
holes
 70
 64
 62
 250
 6
CONTINUOUS
 0
ENDTAB
 0
ENDSEC
0
SECTION
2
ENTITIES
0
SPLINE
8
shape
100
AcDbSpline
210
0
220
0
230
1
70
4
71
3
72
11
73
4
74
4
42
0.0000001
43
0.0000001
44
0.0000000001
40
0
40
0
40
0
40
0
40
1
40
1
40
1
40
2
40
2
40
2
40
2
10
0
20
0
30
0
10
100
20
50
30
0
10
40
20
40
30
0
10
15
20
23
30
0
11
0
21
0
31
0
11
200
21
200
31
0
11
80
21
80
31
0
11
432
21
234
31
0
0
ENDSEC
0
EOF
```

When I'm trying to open it in Autodesk TrueView, I'm getting an error:

> Undefined group code 210 for object on line 54.
>   Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded.

Where is the error? When I'm copying just SPLINE section to the DXF generated by AI everything works fine. So I think I need to add something in the header section or something.

Comment: When I try to open your DXF in AutoCAD, it fails at line 42 (error in table APPID)

Comment: @Maxence right, just change AC1018 to AC1006 and try again. That's my fault. Original file had "AC1006" and I've tried to fix it somehow.

Comment: AC1006 <=> AutoCAD R10. Not sure splines were supported at this time. Their ObjectBirthVersion is AC1012 (AutoCAD R13)

Comment: AutoCAD 2017 crashes with AC1006

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file is DXF version AC1006 which is older than DXF R12. The SPLINE entity
requires at least DXF version  AC1012 DXF R13/R14. But with DXF version AC1012
the tag structure of DXF files is changed (OBJECTS and CLASSES sections, SubClassMarkers ...), so just editing the DXF version 
does not work.

See also: http://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dxfinternals/filestructure.html#minimal-dxf-content

Also the SPLINE entity seems to be invalid, it has no handle (5) and no owner 
tag (330), and the whole AcDbEntity subclass is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your spline is of degree 3 with 11 knots (0, 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2) and 4 control points ( (0,0), (100,50),(40,40),(15,23) ). This might be the problem culprit. You should either have 4 control points and 8 knots or 7 control points and 11 knots.

Comment: Yeah, but the error appears before that. Also, as I said before, this SPLINE worked fine, when I moved SPLINE section to the DXF generated by Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to assign a handle to the SPLINE, since you're specifying `$ACADVER` = `AC1018` = AutoCAD 2004 where item handles are required.

Try adding a 5-code pair right before the layer designation, like so, where `AAAA` is a unique hex-encoded handle:

```
  0
SPLINE
  5     <-- add these two lines
AAAA    <--
  8
shape
100
AcDbSpline
```

Comment: Where do I find this handle? Do I need to declare it somehow? When I'm adding a random number, like 3E, I'm getting the:
> Invalid database handle 3E  on line 50.
Invalid or incomplete DXF input -- drawing discarded.

Comment: Also, the same "DXF base"  (without the handle) works fine, when I'm using the ARC, the LINE and the CIRCLE. The ELLIPSE and the SPLINE don't.